# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0" when making a http request in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to read a json data from an input file, and to pass it as the request to make a http call in python.

Here is the highlights in my python code:

```
with open('input.json') as f:
    raw_data = json.load(f)

cookies = ...
headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json text/plain, */*',
      ...
}

response = requests.put('https://.../template/...02420afe4907', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=raw_data)
```

but it fails for 400 Error. The response contents shows:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0<br>
```

But if I initialize it directly, such as:

```
raw_data = '{"name":"template-123","comment":"",...}'
```

The call can be made successfully.

This is the my input.json looks like:

```
{
   "name":"template-123",
   "comment":"",
   ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this. **I need to get the original data from this file.** Thanks.

Comment: Have you inspected the JSON that you're reading, e.g. by `print()`ing it?

Comment: Don't use `json.load`, probably.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem. E.g. "looks like" for the JSON is far from precise enough to reproduce the promlem (consider [mcve]). The rest is also with too many parts left out that are required to understand the whole. Also, ask yourself whether you really send what you think you send, which could already be the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you pass a `dict` (which is what `raw_data` is) as the `data` argument to `requests.put`, it will be form-encoded, which does not make for valid JSON.  Either pass serialized JSON to `data`:

```
requests.put(..., data=json.dumps(raw_data), ...)
```

or use the `json` keyword and let `requests` do the serialization for you:

```
requests.put(..., json=raw_data, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This does solve my issue. Now I can get the call through.

Comment: using json=my_dictionary did it for me! thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('input.json') as f:
```

did you mean

```
with open('input.json','r') as f:
```

or

```
with open('input.json','rb') as f:
```

if the data is stored as bytes, you have to read it in as 'rb'.